# what is the mysql equivalent of sql server's try catch block

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to migrate a stored procedure from an SQL Server to MySQL. I faced some problem during conversion of a try catch block. I know `DECLARE HANDLER` can be used in place of `TRY`/`CATCH` blocks in MySQL. How can I use `DECLARE HANDLER` to replicate the function of this `CATCH` statement in a MySQL stored procedure?

```
BEGIN CATCH
CLOSE transDetails //cursor name
CLOSE transQuoteOptionDetails//another cursor name
DEALLOCATE transDetails 
DEALLOCATE transQuoteOptionDetails
DECLARE @ErrorMessage   varchar(2000),@ErrorSeverity  tinyint,@ErrorState  tinyint
SET @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
SET @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
Delete From MasterReport_Temp where masterReportRecNo=@masterReportRecNo
Update MasterReport set status=3, errorDescription=@ErrorMessage where recNo=@masterReportRecNo                   

 END CATCH
```

Comment: As you must have read, you declare a handler to deal with a specific error condition. Without seeing the `TRY` block, how could anyone know what the error condition could be?

Comment: thanks @miken32,i want to know is there a way im mysql stored procedure when error occur at some stage then some stetement execute like UPDATE,DELETE and CREATE statement will execute.please give me code if possible

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no try catch equivalent in mysql

But there is way you can handle errors using SIGNAL

> SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error. SIGNAL provides error
>   information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or
>   to the client. Also, it provides control over the error's
>   characteristics (error number, SQLSTATE value, message). Without
>   SIGNAL, it is necessary to resort to workarounds such as deliberately
>   referring to a nonexistent table to cause a routine to return an
>   error.

Comment: thanks @Leonidas Menendez,i know concept of signal in mysql but my question is that is there a way to define multiple statement with HANDLER and HOW to?please give me code